# Windows 7 ebook reader with cloud syncing - .mobi, .epub, .pdf

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, ebook, epub, mobi

What software are available for reading .mobi, .epub and .pdf files on a Windows 7 PC? (free or paid) Cloud syncing features would be great - to have all my books and annotations synced across several computers.

Answer (score 2):

[Mobipocket Reader Desktop](http://www.mobipocket.com/en/downloadsoft/productdetailsreader.asp) (free)

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/products/digitaleditions/) is fairly nice, supports various formats, allows annotations, and can sync changes.

Comment: just installed and it doesn't support mobi.