# How can I sync my progress on ebooks, specifically pdfs across computers?

Tags: sync, cross-platform, ebook

I have ebooks in mobi, epub and pdf formats. For the epubs I have been using [booki.sh](http://booki.sh), but I am at a lost for syncing my progress on pdf files between my windows and linux dual boot and my android tablet/phone. Any suggestions?

EDIT: This is different than the question [Windows 7 ebook reader with cloud syncing - .mobi, .epub, .pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/211435/windows-7-ebook-reader-with-cloud-syncing-mobi-epub-pdf), which was marked as a duplicate of my question, because I was looking for something that can work between android, windows and linux, not just windows 7 as that question concerns.

Comment: Product suggestions are off topic in any case.  Perhaps ask this on an android forum.

Comment: Noted. However an android forum is not any more likely to offer a cross platform solution.